# TFVC force Workspace to match local folder

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

tf vc scorch will make the local match workspace.... I am looking for the opposite...

If I and/remove/edit literally thousands of files, using source control explorer s not a realistic option.

Hoping for a TF VC command (or other CLI option) that say "what I have in my local folder is what I want, mark files as Add/Edit/Change Pending Change As appropriate.  Note these are not files in a solution, so and VS .SLN level approach is not going to match up...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dmitry - I did bot "find a solution" in terms of any type of command, etc... I ended up spending about a week writing and testing a custom application with various ReST API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Visual Studio Team Explorer? In it is the Source Control Explorer, which, allows you to examine your local workspace and diff it to the server workspace. It doesn't require files to be part of a solution.

Comment: Yes, but that will sow the state, but not set the proper pending change... I can click in groups but with 10's of thousands (possible over 110K) files, that is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the workspace, you could copy the files in your local folder and paste them into the workspace. Then you should be able to see the pending changes in the source control explorer or Pending Changes.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Sorry doug, was sidelined (I hate hospitals).....

This is a part of the TFVC tree which ahs been around forever.  I did try:

1)  copying my local files to a different directory
2) clearing local mapped directory.
3) getting from the server (into currently empty directory)
4) copying my files back into place

Unfortunately this did NOT result in a complete set of pending add/edit/rename/delete being created..